# Reseting the state of the objects placed on cell contentview in UITableView in ios

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi in my application I have a searchbar and for loading the results I am using tableview. On this Tableview cell I have button and textfield Now i can able to add elements which are available in tableview to array using button.I am facing one issue that is after adding the data to the array using add buttons and scroll the tableview up and down,the add buttons title is changing actually i don't want to change the title of the button.

I am explaining the cases as such follow

1.After add element to array using add button the title of the button have to changes to "added" it's happening perfectly.Now my issue is if i scroll the table up and down again the buttons titles are changing to "add" again. Please let me know how can i control this.

And how the cell identifier will workit out at this case.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to save which item button is clicked. and when you are scrolling which means tableview loads data again so that in ViewForCell method of tableview you have just added button with default title. so it will change again to default. So what you have to do is that save the id or other identifier of button like

```
 btn.tag = indexpath.row ;
```

so when you click on button you can get tag. now save in to any mutable array like.

```
[AddedData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:btn.tag]];
```

and add one if condition in TableViewforCell method that

```
if([AddedData contains:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexpath.row]]])
{
      btn.titlelabel.text = @"Added";
}
else
{
       btn.titlelabel.text = @"Add";
}
```

Hope it Helps!!